# usb wireless mouse pointer with touchscreen jerky/non-responsive in ubuntu but fine in Windows 10

Tags: usb, 18.04, mouse, touchpad, touchscreen

I have a touchscreen tablet PC, when booted into windows, the wireless usb mouse works fine - I can see the pointer and move it with the mouse.

However, when booting the same tablet PC into Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 64bit, the mouse pointer is either jerky or not responsive - it does not move.

Can you advise, please?

Could it be that Ubuntu is detecting both the mouse and the touchscreen and is not currently very good at handling both like Windows can? In which case perhaps I would need to disable the touchscreen. e.g. as in question [I need to permanently disable the touchscreen input - Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766731/i-need-to-permanently-disable-the-touchscreen-input-ubuntu-16-04)

Thank you.

Hardware involved:
Panasonic FZ-G1 MkIII Toughpad
Logitech M187 Wireless USB Mouse

Answer (score 1):

i just use this command line to fix my wireless mouse. It's working fine on my Ubuntu 18.04. So just copy and paste my command line below:-

1. Install XServer:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
   ```
2. Remove old XServer:

   ```
   sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
   ```

After this finished, reboot your PC...
and see the magic..hehehehe

Comment: dont forget to unplug and reconnect it back..after reboot the system. Good luck..

Comment: WARNING Take a backup! I ran these commands on Kubuntu 18.04 and my x display broke. I had to reinstall my OS.

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround that seems to solve the issue as it seems to be an peculiarity with the usb hub that I am using.

I have a UGreen P/N 30412 3 port USB 3.0 hub with card reader. This hub is powered from the port it is plugged into. It is plugged into the USB 3.0/superspeed port of the tablet PC, the Panasonic FZ-G1 MkIII.

The logitech M187 usb wireless mouse receiver and Goldtouch GTP0044UK usb wired keyboard are both plugged into the hub.

The workaround seems to be to swap the port number/positions that the receiver and keyboard are plugged into. Specifically, if the keyboard is plugged into port 1 - i.e. the port closest to the cable from the hub that leads to the tablet (host) and the usb mouse wireless receiver in port 2. Both keyboard and mouse work fine in this configuration and after reboot.

Before this, the mouse wireless usb reciever was on port 1 and the keyboard on port 2.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that helped me on 18.04 is turning off zoom, found in this question:
[How can I get rid of mouse lag under Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/763413/how-can-i-get-rid-of-mouse-lag-under-ubuntu)