# Disable touchscreen while using pen

Tags: command-line, lenovo, touchscreen, wacom, krita

I just installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo L390. Works well.

Theres one problem tho: When using Krita, I use the built in pen to draw. Sadly, the touchscreen is still active, so a whole bunch of lines keep appearing as I draw.

Tho, I don't want to disable the touchscreen completely: I only want it disabled when the computer detects that the pen is close to the screen. (The pen needs to be charged, if that helps with anything)

I found out that the following post helped me disable my touchscreen, while keeping the pen working:
https://askubuntu.com/a/780177/1009141

So my question is, how can I disable the touchscreen only when the pen is in use?

Comment: Here is how I'm disabling my touchpad conditionally, probably you can adapt it to your case: [How do I disable the touchpad when the lid is twisted or closed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/980997/566421)