# How to disable touch screen permanently?

Tags: drivers, touchscreen

Recently i have moved to ubuntu from windows. I have a problem with my touch screen so i have disabled it by xinput command. But whenever my system is restarted the driver is getting enabled. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: @singrium "duplicate" in turn refers to a documentation page where reference is still made to `gnome-session-properties`. In other words: outdated.

Comment: @singrium no i want to disable it permanently

Comment: You can add that command to **startup applications** so every time you open your PC, the command will be automatically run at startup and by this the touch screen will be disabled. Check [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/780177/822295)

Comment: try 
    xinput

then locate your touchscreens number #

xinput disable #

I think that is permanent. If not then make a script and put it in startup apps, which is what I have done. funny enough my touch pen works. a much better experience IMO without the touchscreen, being touchy, going awry.

power key, "start", "startup applications", add button.

bash "/home/MyScripts/DisableTouchscreen.sh"

my script is for my display ELAN, so you wont need the number.
note that those numbers can change on reboot.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
touchscreen=""
pen=""

OIFS=$IFS
search=""ELAN0732:00""

# note that the pen didnt show up until I mapped the standard one or clicked the screen.
# so need to do that first
echo $search

list=$(xinput | grep $search | grep pointer)
echo "list $list"


if [ -f tempxinput.txt ]
then    
    echo " removing tempxinput"
    rm tempxinput.txt
fi



device_id=$(echo "$list" | sed -n 's/.*ELAN0732:00.*id=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p')


for i in $device_id
do
echo "id is $i"
xinput disable $i 
done

if that is an answer, I can put it in as such and tidy up the script

Answer (score 0):

You successfully found the command that can disable your touch screen. [Other questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766731/i-need-to-permanently-disable-the-touchscreen-input-ubuntu-16-04) indicate how that can be found

To have this command automatically executed when you log in, add it to your autostart applications. These applications are defined by `.desktop` launcher files that reside in the hidden folder `.config/autostart` in your home folder.

In older Ubuntu versions, a graphical tool, `gnome-session-properties`, allowed to create such `.desktop` files. This tool, however, is not included in recent Ubuntu versions. However, you can easily create such a `.desktop` folder yourself using a text editor.

**1. Create a desktop file**

Open your editor, paste the following snippet and fill it out:

```
#!/usr/bin/env xdg-open
[Desktop Entry]
Categories=Utility;
Comment=
Exec=
Icon=
Name=
StartupNotify=false
Type=Application
Version=1.0
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Hidden=false
```

You can fill out the `Comment=`, `Icon=` and `Name=` fields as you see fit, and probably these lines can also be removed. Important is your `Exec=` line: complete that with the command you need to execute to disable the touch screen. The line `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true` is optional, but if it is there, should be set to true. Replace by "false" to prevent the laucher from being run during start up. `Hidden=false` also is optional. If you would set it to `true`, the effect would be the same as deleting the launcher altogether.

Save the text file as, for example, `notouchscreen.desktop`.

**2. Move the `desktop` file to your startup folder**

To be in effect, the file should reside in `.config/autostart` in your home folder. `.config` is a hidden folder. You can see it by revealing "hidden files" in the file manager. You can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to toggle the visibility of hidden files and folders. Under `config`, you will find the `autostart` folder. Move the file there.

Logout and log back in. When you logged back in, the touch screen should have been disabled automatically.

**Delaying your command if needed**

If it did not work, you may need to insert a little delay in the command so that it is executed only when your desktop is loaded. That is possible with a "sleep" command. To delay running your command for 3 seconds, use the following `Exec=` line:

```
Exec=sh -c "sleep 3 && put your command here"
```

**Run the autostart command for all users on the system**

This will disable the touch screen for your current user only. If you want this to work for all users, then you must repeat this for each account. Alternatively, if you have root (administrator) privileges, then move your `.desktop` file to `/etc/xgd/autostart/', where lauchers reside that are run when any user logs in.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: If this works for you, then please accept the question.