# New update ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS causes me log out of my account multiple times

Tags: 18.04, updates, touchscreen

Before the update every time I logged in I used to disable my laptop's touchscreen. But since the new update I am not able to disable the touchscreen.

Command **`xinput disable 9`** doesn't works anymore. Someone please help. I have other methods too but none of them worked.

And also I get logged out my account and all applications gets closed automatically and I have to re login. It usually happens when I use the touchscreen. This is only happening after this new update.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic




Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-touch:15                         id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:15                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:15              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:15                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F3, login, then what does `xinput --list` show?

Comment: please have a look i edited it

Answer (score 0):

Edit `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf` file and in

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
EndSection
```

replace `libinput` in driver section to `evdev`, so it will be:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchscreen catchall"
        MatchIsTouchscreen "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
EndSection
```

Then restart and try to login.

People [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/766731/i-need-to-permanently-disable-the-touchscreen-input-ubuntu-16-04) did the same for evdev configuration making it invalid by replacing `evdev` to `libinput`. In this way they disabled touchscreen.

If you have `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` file, then change `evdev` to `libinput` in Driver section for this case.